# How to compare a multidimensional array with one array element?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array as follows,

```
$array1 = Array(
            'id'       => Array(1 => 19, 2 => 47),
            'name'     => Array(1 => 'Alex Paul', 21 => 'sdfs'),
            'category' => Array(1 => 1, 21 => 2)
             );
```

Also I have an array element

```
     $res['id'][1]= 47;
```

I want to **check** `$res['id'][1]` is present in `$array1`  or not.
How to solve this issue

Comment: this looks all to be php, why is javascript tagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `in_array` function

```
if(in_array($res['id'][1], $array1['id']))
    echo 'Here';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check using [in_array()](https://www.php.net/in_array) in php

```
  if(in_array($res['id'][1],$array1['id'])) {
      echo $res['id'][1] . ' exist in array';
  } else {
     echo 'not exist';

  }
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](https://eval.in/95583)</kbd>

Comment: you are just checking in the `$array1['id']`

Comment: If I am think  logically, then OP compare with `$res['id'][1]` which is id so I have not consider whole array and just check with `id`.

Comment: you are right, but the question does not mention comparing with just `id`,

Answer (score 0):

This checks that `$res['id'][1]` is present in the whole `$array1` or not :

```
$present = false;
foreach($array1 as $val){
    if(in_array($res['id'][1],$val)) $present = true;
}
echo $present ? "Yes" : "No";
```

If you just want to check in `$array1['id'][1]`, as the other answers are saying,

it is as simple as this :

```
echo in_array($res['id'][1],$array1['id'][1]) ? "Yes" : "No" ;
```

Documentation of [**in_array()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try like,

```
   $array1=Array ( 'id' => Array (  1 => 19, 2 => 47 ),
           'name' => Array ( 1 => 'Alex Paul', 21 => 'sdfs' ),
           'category' => Array ( 1 => 1, 21 => 2 ));

   $res['id'][1]= 47;

   if(in_array($res['id'][1], $array1['id']))
     echo 'found';
```